# numsessions limit hits on parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, plesk

I hope someone can help me figure out this issue. 
I have a windows based VPS with 6GB of ram and enough disk space.
I have only 3 websites hosted and all three are not advertised publicly, so no one could access.

The issue is the server is slow in response whenever we try to load the sites in browser or in RDP or thru Parallel Plesk Control. Everything slow to response.

I have every 1 minute to 3 , from green zone to red zone a lot of numsessions limit hits. 
I have browsed SO and read Parallel doc and even browse their forum and no one has mentioned a real solution. They say that numsessions is hit when many sessions of rdp or Parallel Plesk Control are left open.In my case no one has access to the server and no one is logging to the server either. I have rebooted the server many times and only one session was open and that was to control server via virtuoso (Parallel Power Control) and same the numsessions is hit again within 3 min of reboot.

I have talk to the idiots at 1and1 (where we bought the VPS xxl) and they have no clue saying it is not our problem but yours or MS Windows! I have not installed any third party or even proprietary software on server which could cause the issue. The server is brand new and only created new sites via Parallel Plesk control. Emails are not working either. 
Windows Event viewer doesnt show much information either.

Last resort is to re-image the server which may solve issue but I doubt since the issue seems to be from the server when we bought it.

anyone could shed their wisdom light on this please?

Thanks

Comment: You can ask 1and1 to open ticket in parallels support or contact parallels support directly.

Comment: I spent 1 week with their email support, everytime someone else would reply and no one was able to answer correctly, I finally called them up, and again on the phone spent many many minutes and finally one guy told me that these numsessions hit were NOT MINE but another user on the same VPS, and I ve been asked to buy Dedicated server as they cant block or limit HIS resources! I ve asked for refund and went elsewhere!

Comment: It's also maybe Virtuozzo(PVC) bug. Hope someone from 1and1 have see this post and fix this issue to provide better service.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed my resource log full of these as well. I think the issue is that a session is counted as soon as a RDP connection is made - so bots trying common admin passwords count towards this.

The real issue is as there is no way I can find to filter these from the resource alerts you basically can't find the real problem you have as the logs are just full of numsesssions.

Comment: This should be placed as a comment instead of an answer.
This does not provide an answer to the question. It's better to leave a comment below.